# Running Vite with a proxy returns error 500

Tags: vue.js, proxy, vite

There is a web-server running on http://localhost:9000, which I would like to use with Vue development server as proxy. Vite is listening on http://localhost:5173. However, Vite returns error 500. Do I omit anything?

**Setup**

I have installed a basic standard Vue application:

```
λ npm create vue@latest
Need to install the following packages:
  create-vue@3.7.5
Ok to proceed? (y)

Vue.js - The Progressive JavaScript Framework

√ Project name: ... vue-project
√ Add TypeScript? ... _No_ / Yes
√ Add JSX Support? ... _No_ / Yes
√ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? ... _No_ / Yes
√ Add Pinia for state management? ... _No_ / Yes
√ Add Vitest for Unit Testing? ... _No_ / Yes
√ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? » No
√ Add ESLint for code quality? ... _No_ / Yes

Scaffolding project in C:\tmp\vue-proxy\vue-project...

Done. Now run:

  cd vue-project
  npm install
  npm run dev

C:\tmp\vue-proxy
λ cd vue-project\ && npm install && npm run dev

added 25 packages, and audited 26 packages in 53s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> vue-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.4.9  ready in 780 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

Added server.proxy option to vite.config.js:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:9000"
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

**Expected:**

```
λ curl http://localhost:5173/api/
{"message":"Hi there (root)"}

λ curl http://localhost:9000
{"message":"Hi there (root)"}
```

**Observed:**

```
λ curl -i http://localhost:5173/api
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sun, 24 Sep 2023 08:26:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

λ curl http://localhost:9000
{"message":"Hi there (root)"}
```

Vite:

```
10:22:08 [vite] http proxy error at /api:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:9000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491876/vite-proxy-econnrefused-with-node-v17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three places that need to be fixed to make this work:

1. Add `server.host: "0.0.0.0"` option.
2. Use host IP in `server.proxy: { "/api/": "http://127.0.0.1:9000" }`
3. The proxied server must respond to same path as in the server.proxy settings: `http://localhost:9000/api/`:

```
λ curl localhost:9000/api/
{"message":"Hi there"}

λ curl localhost:5173/api/
{"message":"Hi there"}
```